# How do you get changes to laravel model in hasMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have model "Contact" which hasMany "Address".
When saving the Contact with a new Address

```
...
//$contact = some instance of Contact
$contact->addresses()->save(new Address(['street' => '4811 Example Dr.']));

dd($contact->getChanges()); // returns null
// dd($contact->addresses()->getChanges()); // method not available   
// dd($contact->addresses->getChanges()); // method not available
```

How can I check which changes were actually made after the save call?

Answer (score 2):

`$contact->getChanges()` returns null because `getChanges()` tries to see if there were any changes in contacts table which were not, hence null.

`$contact->addresses()->getChanges()` won't work either because `$contact->addresses()` does not return an instance of Address modal.

You could use a simple check `save` response for verification as it returns boolean.

```
$addressSavedSucccessfully = $contact->addresses()->save(new Address(['street' => '4811 Example Dr.']));

if ($addressSavedSucccessfully) {
    dd('address was saved correctly');
} else {
    dd('something went wrong');
}
```

*I hope it helps.*

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking if the save was successful or not.  I'm asking what changes were saved for a related model.  The getChanges() call returns a list of attributes that were saved/modified - but only for the immediate model.  So how do I find them for models that are related?

Comment: I mean if the save was successful, the immediate changes were the same for which you ran query..in this case would be "street" field in addresses table...does that make sense?

Comment: Ah... yes that makes sense, and maybe my example was too simple to express the point fully, but it's not really what I'm after because Address can be an updated as well (doesn't have to be new)... I'll have to revise my initial question to include the additional complexity - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below line returns bolean. You can check its return value.

```
$value = $contact->addresses()->save(new Address(['street' => '4811 Example Dr.']));


if($value){
   //it is saved
}else{
  //it is not saved    
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not asking if the save was successful or not.  I'm asking what changes were saved for a related model.  The getChanges() call returns a list of attributes that were saved/modified - but only for the immediate model.

Answer (score 0):

*edited
try this

```
if (!$contact) {
   $changes = $contact->getChanges();
}
```

Comment: give return/dd() to that variable
`return $changes = $contact->getChanges();`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - why should one try that? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from that code

Comment: Additionally this code would fail: If contact is false (because it's null) then $contact->getChanges() would fail because you'd be trying to get a member on a non-object.  If $contact is an object, it won't be false, and won't enter the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Give the below a try. It's working for me

```
$this->loadMissing('address');
$address = $this->address;
$address->fill($addressFieldValue);
$address->save();
address->getChanges();
```